# ReferenceMany in Doctorine with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony with Doctrine.

The annotation for $members (getMembers() returns this variable):

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="something", storeAs="dbRef")
 * @Assert\NotNull
 * @JMS\Groups({"Default", "something"})
 */
protected $members;
```

The controller: (I used $form->submit)

```
public function updateAction($id, Request $request)
{

    $project = $this->fetchProject($id);
    $oldMembers = $project->getMembers();

    $form = $this->createForm(...);
    $form->submit($request->request->all(), false);

    $newMembers = $project->getMembers();
    ...
    $this->persist(...);
```

I add new members in the form and submit it but the '$oldMembers' and the '$newMembers' are the same! which is not desirable!

both of them are referring to the the new data (getMembers()). but I need to keep $oldMembers separate from $newMembers. how?

Answer (score 1):

try to refresh the entity manager like this:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em->refresh($project);
```

---

Or you can add member manually if refresh doesn't work

You are using a Form, but if you can add manually members like this:

```
$project->addMember($member);
```

Into your entity you can have a method like this:

```
public function addMember(Member $member)
{
    $this->member[] = $member;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I have the same addMember. the "$this->em->refresh($project);" made an "Internal server error" for me. "Notice: Undefined property: ...\\Controller\\ProjectController::$em"

Comment: I don't know for the internal server error, try to view your log, I think that addMe,ber isn't called when you save from the form

Comment: 'em' is a part of 'FOSRestController'?

Comment: em is the EntityManager @Adel you need to define it somewhere